# How can I get the position of bits

Tags: java, algorithm, binary, bit-manipulation

I have a decimal number which I need to convert to binary and then find the position of one's in that binary representation.

Input is 5 whose binary is `101` and Output should be

```
1
3
```

Below is my code which only provides output as `2` instead I want to provide the position of one's in binary representation. How can I also get position of set bits starting from 1?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(countBits(5));
}

private static int countBits(int number) {
    boolean flag = false;

    if (number < 0) {
        flag = true;
        number = ~number;
    }
    int result = 0;
    while (number != 0) {
        result += number & 1;
        number = number >> 1;
    }
    return flag ? (32 - result) : result;
}
```

Comment: Note: The code to check if `number` is negative isn't necessary.  If you use the `>>>` operator instead of `>>`, then zeroes will be shifted in on the left (instead of 1's being shifted into negative numbers), so `number` will eventually be 0 and `result` will always be the correct count.

Comment: If you're trying to return the position of the 1 bits, then using `>>>` will be necessary.  If you try to handle negative numbers specially, your job will be a lot more complex.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your idea of having `countBits` return the result, instead of putting a `System.out.println` inside the method, is generally the best approach.  If you want it to return a list of bit positions, the analogue would be to have your method return an array or some kind of List, like:

```
private static List<Integer> bitPositions(int number) {
```

As I mentioned in my comments, you will make life a lot easier for yourself if you use `>>>` and get rid of the special code to check for negatives.  Doing this, and adapting the code you already have, gives you something like

```
private static List<Integer> bitPositions(int number) {
    List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();
    int position = 1;
    while (number != 0) {
        if (number & 1 != 0) {
            positions.add(position);
        }
        position++;
        number = number >>> 1;
    }
    return positions;
}
```

Now the caller can do what it wants to print the positions out.  If you use `System.out.println` on it, the output will be `[1, 3]`.  If you want each output on a separate line:

```
for (Integer position : bitPositions(5)) {
     System.out.println(position);
}
```

In any case, the decision about how to print the positions (or whatever else you want to do with them) is kept separate from the logic that computes the positions, because the method returns the whole list and doesn't have its own `println`.

(By the way, as Alex said, it's most common to think of the lower-order bit as "bit 0" instead of "bit 1", although I've seen hardware manuals that call the low-order bit "bit 31" and the high-order bit "bit 0".  The advantage of calling it "bit 0" is that a 1 bit in position N represents the value 2<sup>N</sup>, making things simple.  My code example calls it "bit 1" as you requested in your question; but if you want to change it to 0, just change the initial value of `position`.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you explain why we use bitwise operator whenever we want to convert any decimal number to binary? Is there any logical reason for this? Actually I am confuse why bitwise operator is coming into the picture. And why we specifically used `>>>` here.

Comment: The binary representation of a number **is** bits.  You asked to get the positions of 1's in binary representation; that's exactly the same as asking where the 1 bits are.  That's why we use bitwise operators.  Also, the method is not "converting" decimal numbers to binary.  `number` is already stored in binary in the computer; the decimal-to-binary conversion took place a long time ago, when the compiler saw the number `5` in your main method and converted it to binary.

Comment: As for `>>>`, I thought you understood why negative numbers were a problem, and that's why you were handling them specially.  I guess you don't?  When a number is negative, the leftmost bit is 1.  When the leftmost bit is 1, the `>>` operator will insert another 1 on the left when it shifts the bits over.  If you're counting the number of 1's or looking for the 1 bits, this extra 1 will mess you up.  `>>>` does not do this.  It always inserts a 0 at the left.

Comment: logic fails for number 7

Comment: @BleedCode Please explain: (1) what logic are you talking about [is this with the `bitPositions` method, or something else?], (2) what output were you expecting, and what did you get.

Comment: Operator '&' cannot be applied to 'int', 'boolean'

Answer (score 5):

**Binary representation:** Your number, like anything on a modern day (non-quantum) computer, is already a binary representation in memory, as a sequence of bits of a given size.

**Bit operations**
You can use bit shifting, bit masking, 'AND', 'OR', 'NOT' and 'XOR' [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) to manipulate them and get information about them on the level of individual bits.

**Your example**

For your example number of 5 (101) you mentioned that your expected output would be `1, 3`. This is a bit odd, because generally speaking one would start counting at 0, e.g. for 5 as a `byte` (8 bit number):

```
     76543210  <-- bit index
5    00000101
```

So I would expect the output to be `0` and `2` because the bits at those bit indexes are set (`1`).

Your sample implementation shows the code for the function

```
private static int countBits(int number)
```

Its name and signature imply the following behavior for any implementation:

- It takes an integer value `number` and returns *a single* output value.
- It is intended to count how many bits are set in the input `number`.

I.e. it does not match at all with  what you described as your intended functionality.

**A solution**

You can solve your problem using a combination of a 'bit shift' (`>>`) and an `AND` (`&`) operation.

```
int index = 0; // start at bit index 0

while (inputNumber != 0) { // If the number is 0, no bits are set

    // check if the bit at the current index 0 is set
    if ((inputNumber & 1) == 1)         
        System.out.println(index);  // it is, print its bit index.

    // advance to the next bit position to check
    inputNumber = inputNumber >> 1; // shift all bits one position to the right
    index = index + 1;              // so we are now looking at the next index.
}
```

If we were to run this for your example input number '5', we would see the following:

```
iteration   input  76543210     index    result
1           5      00000101     0        1 => bit set.
2           2      00000010     1        0 => bit not set.
3           1      00000001     2        1 => bit set.
4           0      00000000     3        Stop, because inputNumber is 0
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to keep track of what position you're on, and when `number & 1` results in 1, print out that position. It look something like:

```
...
int position = 1;
while (number != 0) {
    if((number & 1)==1)
        System.out.println(position);
    result += number & 1;
    position += 1;
    number = number >> 1;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way around working with bit-wise operations to solve your problem.
`Integer.toBinaryString(int number)` converts an integer to a String composed of zeros and ones. This is handy in your case because you could instead have:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    countBits(5);
}

public static void countBits(int x) {
  String binaryStr = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
  int length = binaryStr.length();
  for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    if(binaryStr.charAt(i)=='1')
      System.out.println(length-1);
  }
}
```

It bypasses what you might be trying to do (learn bitwise operations in Java), but makes the code look cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of Integer.lowestOneBit and Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros instantly gives the position of the lowest 1-Bit, and returns 32 iff the number is 0.

Therefore, the following code returns the positions of 1-Bits of the number *number* in ascending order:

```
public static List<Integer> BitOccurencesAscending(int number)
{
    LinkedList<Integer> out = new LinkedList<>();
    int x = number;
    while(number>0)
    {
        x = Integer.lowestOneBit(number);
        number -= x;
        x = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(x);
        out.add(x);
    }
    return out;
}
```