# get position of leftmost 0 bit of a number

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to get the leftmost position of number 0 of an integer

```
    int a = 83
```

For example, binary of 83 is 1010011 so we have have position of leftmost bit 0 is 6th. I wonder is there a way only using bitwise operator to find the answer?

Comment: Here : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429821/how-can-i-get-the-position-of-bits) you could try to exploit this method. It is not possible through only bitwise operator, though.

Comment: For what purpose? NB Your description is imprecise. You appear to be looking for the leftmost 0 bit to the right of the leftmost 1 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
private static int leftmostZeroBit(int a) {
    int b = Integer.highestOneBit(a);
    return (b == 0 ? -1 : 31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(a ^ b ^ (b - 1)));
}

private static int leftmostZeroBit(long a) {
    long b = Long.highestOneBit(a);
    return (b == 0 ? -1 : 63 - Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(a ^ b ^ (b - 1)));
}
```

**Explanation**

Don't know if this is efficient compared to a simple search loop over the bits, but you can use the following methods to help:
[`Integer.highestOneBit(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#highestOneBit-int-)
[`Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros-int-)

They each use bit-manipulation, so they take less than 32 iterations (or 64 iterations if using the `Long` versions).

Given an example input value of `1101011`, we want to invert it to `0010100`.

Remember, an `int` has 32 bits, so there are 25 0-bits to the left of those, so to invert it we need to XOR with the mask `1111111`.

That mask can be calculated by calling `highestOneBit()`, which gives us `1000000`, subtracting 1 gives `0111111`, and combining them gives the mask.

Once we've done the XOR and gotten `0010100`, we calculate `31 - numberOfLeadingZeros()` to find the position of the leading 1-bit, which is 4 in this example.

We can then define that we want result to be `-1` for invalid input:

- `000` is invalid, since there are no leftmost 0-bit without a 1-bit
- `111` is invalid, since there are no 0-bits after 1-bits

That gives us the code at the top of the answer.

**Test**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(0x6B); // example in answer
    test(0x53); // example in question (83)
    test(0x29);
    test(0x14);
    test(0x0A);
    test(0x05);
    test(0x02);
    test(0x01);
    test(0x00);
    test(0x80000000);
    test(0xFFFFFFFE);
}
private static void test(int a) {
    System.out.printf("%32s: %d%n", Integer.toBinaryString(a), leftmostZeroBit(a));
}
```

**Output**

```
                         1101011: 4
                         1010011: 5
                          101001: 4
                           10100: 3
                            1010: 2
                             101: 1
                              10: 0
                               1: -1
                               0: -1
10000000000000000000000000000000: 30
11111111111111111111111111111110: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    int a = 83
    int mask = 1;
    // This loop finds the leftmost 1 bit
    while(a > mask) 
        mask <<= 1;
    mask >>= 1;
    // This loop starts from the leftmost 1 bit and searches for the first 0 going right
    while((a & mask) != 0) 
        mask >>= 1;

    System.out.println(Math.log(mask) / Math.log(2) + 1); // 6
```

The last "log" part is necessary to give the position index of the leftmost 0 bit

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can understand you can use Bitwise operator but alone won't do it. You have to use Conditional Operator to get the output since program has to check the last occurrence of 0 from right to left or first occurrence of 0 from left to right.