# Array with Binary, find where the 1's are and output the index of the 1's as a subset

Tags: java

The goal for this code is to find the number of 1's appear in the array and basically create another array that has the index of where the 1 appeared. For example say I have an array {0, 0, 1, 0, 1} the output should be {3, 5}. (in this case, we ignore the first index of the array) This is what I have so far:

```
public class array_binary {

    static String string(int [] B) {

        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();


        for(i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
            if(B[i]==1) {
                result.add(i+1);
            }   
        }

    }
```

but the code is not outputting anything...I am quite stuck on what to do next? Is this even a good start to the code?

Comment: `i <= B.length;` should be `i < B.length;`

Comment: `if(n==1)` will never be true, you never change the value of `n` from `0`. It needs to be `if(B[i] == 1)`

Comment: @GBlodgett thank you for that!

Comment: And also, you want to print `i`, not `B[i]`. The former is your index, the latter is the value at your array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the position of bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429821/how-can-i-get-the-position-of-bits)

Answer (score -1):

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class array_binary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] input = {0,0,1,0,1};
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i =0 ; i< input.length;i++)
        {
            if (input[i]== 1)
            {
                result.add(i+1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());


    }

}
```

Few pointer :

1. We are not actually ignoring the first index, in arrays, index start
           with 0, but we humans read it from 1, so that's your sample data
           says `3,5` , it should be `2,4` in terms of array index.
2. I have used ArrayList, it's basically an array only but of dynamic size. So rather than declaring the size in starting, we
       declare an array and keep adding stuff to it as needed.

Comment: `.toString()` functions returns a string datatype. So if you have `String res = result.toString()` and then do `return res` in your function, it will return a string.

Comment: In Java, class names are written in CamelCase.

Comment: Add res =result.toString(), after the loop. Because after the loop only result variable will have anything in it. Before it’s empty.

Comment: Add this line in main function after you initialised B `System.out.println(setToString(B));`

Comment: thank you so much for all your help! you are amazing!

Comment: Look for `.replace` function in strings. There are many variant, but basic one would be like `.replace("[","}")`. Look into it.